# Firebase pricing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a report from firebase that i have exceeded my daily quota. can anyone explain this table to me? especially with the $0.06 per 100k documents? does it mean when exceed the free quota of document reads per day I will only pay $0.06 if i reach 100k documents that day? cuz i have exceeded my free quota for the day and i can't get my collections from the database.

[image: firebase pricing from google]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does it mean when exceed the free quota of document reads per day I will only pay $0.06 if i reach 100k documents that day?

Yes, you will pay 6 cents per 100k document reads beyond the first free 50k.

Comment: oh i see so if i make 200k reads a day, i will pay only 6 cents? since the remaining 50 isn't up to 100k?

Comment: No, you will be charged 1/100000th of $0.06 for each document read above the free quota, so $0.09 for your example. The table just shows the charge per 100k document reads to make the monetary value more readable as most of us find that easier than translating "$0.000000006 per document read" to an actual amount.